# What is the serif font used in the King's Hawaiian logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I was recently enjoying some tasty King's Hawaiian Bread. I noticed their font for their logo and would like find a font with a similar look. I ran their logo through [What The Font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) and it returned Kuenstler 480 Black as a possible match. This is close it is lacking the "swooshes" that you see in the N and H. (I do not know the technical term.)

Does anyone know what font is used in their logo or a close match?

For those not familiar with their logo here is a copy:

[image: King's Hawaiian Logo]

---

Here's those characters in [Kuenstler 480 Black (preview generated by **Fontzone**)](http://fontzone.net/font-details/Kuenstler+480+Black+BT/?preview=KING%27S%20HAWAIIAN) for comparison. It's similar, but not a clean match:

[image]

Comment: I hope they didn't pay much for that. The `H` is an atrocity!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aloha, that is a great question and I love our font too! I think what others have shared about Garamond is a close match but the KING'S HAWAIIAN logo is actually a custom font so there isn't really an exact match, just something close. You might be able to find another font that has a similar for just the N and the H. Mahalo for the support and have a nice week! If you have more questions, feel free to reach out to us at khcares@kingshawaiian.com.

Courtney
KING'S HAWAIIAN Consumer Care

Comment: Oh! This is awesome, I laughed out loud. It hasn't topped 15º (F) for a few days. I'd love to be in your temps. Thanks for the warm smile!

Comment: While it's awesome to see a response from the company itself, this doesn't seem to actually answer the question at all, apart from saying it was a "custom font" - well we already knew that from the swooshes, etc - it kind of goes without saying.

Answer (score 6):

WhatTheFont picked it as [**ITC Garamond Bold**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/garamond/std-bold/), which has that slightly rounded quality.

[image]

Comment: I second that. ITC's version is the match, with awful swash variants added by some heartless individual. The previous suggestion of Serial isn't even close.

Comment: Agreed, this is a better match than my answer. I was misled by the fact that ITC Garamond has a symmetric apostrophe -- but it turns out that "apostrophe" in the logo isn't really an apostrophe at all, but a right single quote.

Comment: This is certainly close, though I have a hunch the original, though modified, was based off a variant of this.

Answer (score 3):

Except for the "swooshes", it looks a lot like some [Garamond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garamond) variant, such as [Garamond Serial](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/softmaker/garamond-serial/) or [TS Garamond](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ef-typeshop/garamond/).  Here's a sample of Garamond Serial Xbold for comparison:

[image: Garamond Serial Xbold]

I suspect that many of the details that do differ, such as the curved bar in the A, the missing serif on the K and the flourishes on the N and the H, are likely to be custom tweaks made by the logo designer.

Comment: Thanks, that is a very close match. I did come across another font by pure accident that is called [Pieces of Eight](http://www.dafont.com/pieces-of-eight.font). It is also similar and has the swooshes. Thanks again for your help.